"SixJsymbol" function unable to be simplified with long run times due to not real components despite including the assumptions
I'm trying to perform some quantum mechanical calculations using Wigner-Eckhart theorem by running them through Mathematica. However, despite including the assumptions the calculation is unable to be completed.
sj = SixJSymbol[{l, S, j}, {1, j, S}];

Creates 6Jsymbol
assum = sj [[1, 1]][[2]];
sj = Simplify[sj[[1, 1]][[1]], assum]

Creates variable,assum, which is assigned second value at the 1,1 index which contains the assumptions.
SJ is then simplified calling the first value at the 1,1 position which contains the expression we are looking for.
Simple code but it wont evaluate.
This is the error message I receive
"Reduce was unable to prove that a radical of an expression containing 
only real variables and parameters is real-valued. If you are 
interested only in solutions for which all radicals contained in the 
input are real-valued, use Reduce with domain argument Reals"
I am a novice at mathematica could someone help me here. In the case of the same code for the 3Jsymbol i recieve no problems.
**edit would just using the real function work in this case? I dont understand in what cases you would use complex expand instead?
sj = Re[Simplify[sj[[1, 1]][[1]], assum]]


What do you want to achieve?  In most quantum mechanical calculations I know you want to evaluate a 6J symbol for a given set of l, S and j which SixJSymbol perfectly does. The simplification you try to achieve would generate an analytic expression for this, which may or may not exist ( check e.g. Rose's book). But what would it help for calculations?

I hope to use it to obtain an analytical expression for the magnetic energy operator, which in the case of J = J' simplifies to M * g, where g is the Lande g factor. This is following Ch 17 of Cowan's "Theory of atomic structure and spectra".

But SixJSymbol did return an "analytical" expression! It is there, in sj[[1, 1, 1]]: $$-\frac{2 \sqrt{(2 j-1)!} \sqrt{(2 S-1)!} (-1)^{-j-l-S} \left(j^2+j-l^2-l+S^2+S\right)}{\sqrt{(2 j+2)!} \sqrt{(2 S+2)!}}$$ The expression you are simplifying only contains conditions at which this expression is valid (because it is 0 otherwise).
